# What would be a safe way or alt. to run a command as root from php script?

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, root

Just as the question says... I've read up a few articles, others says just don't do it, but yet fail to mention a safe way. I know it hazardous to give it sudo access or root, but I was thinking about running a script that has root access through root.

One post was talking about a binary wrapper, but I did not fully understand it when I attempted it and when I tried to do a search to understand I didn't find anything that explain it well.

So, what would be a good-safe way? I don't even need to have a detailed explanation. You can just point me to a good source to start reading.

Thanks.

Specs:
Ubuntu Server 14.04

EDIT:
Commands I am talking about is mkdir, rmdir with an absolute path. Create user, remove user (which is why I need root) and edit some Apache files for me.

Comment: what command in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They fail to provide a safe way because, IMHO, there isn't one.  Or, to put it another way, are you confident that your code that protects the create user and add user functions is cleverer than the hackers code that tries to gain access to your system via the back door you've built?

I can't think of a good reason for a web site to create a new system-level user.  Usually web applications run using system users that are created for them by an administrator.  The users inside your web site only have meaning for that web site so creating a new web site user gains that user no system privileges at all.  That said, it's your call as to whether you need to do it or not.

In those cases where system operations are necessary a common approach is to build a background process that carries out those actions independently of the web site.  The web site and that background process communicate via anything that works and is secure - sockets, a shared database, a text file, TCP-IP, etc.  That separation allows you to control what actions can be requested and build in the necessary checks and balances.  Of course it's not a small job, but you're not the first person to want to do this so I'd look for an existing tool that supports this administration.

Comment: I believe cpanel does this, do they not?
Also, makes me think.. By putting them in DB and have it monitor the DB for any changes to carry out, that is what you're basically talking about?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it, basically a work queue that your web page adds requests to and the background process reads from.  That let's you run the background process with the rights it needs while keeping the web site locked down.  Its still a backdoor but it's a more well-defined and managable one.  I build Windows systems so I know about C# frameworks to do this kind of thing but couldn't quickly find a Linux / PHP background processing engine.

Comment: I know you can create a script that never ends in bash that will sleep until it detects a change in a file then executes. It just hard trying to make something reasonable secured without me sitting there to manage it 24/7.